# How to do scrolling inside infinite load table or list

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

While continuing to learn the robot framework, I encountered a problem with scrolling internal elements like async table or list. I have a table, which by default has 15 items available, to get to the next 15 - 30 - 45 etc I need to scroll to make elements loaded. How can I do this using robot framework?

What have I tried: Scroll Element Into View keyword and Execute Javascript

```
Scroll Element Into View  xpath=//*[@id="tickets"]/tbody/tr[16]

and also

Execute JavaScript  window.document.evaluate("//*[@id="tickets"]/tbody/tr[16]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView(true);
```

I receive ElementNotInteractableException.

Comment: without HTML it is very difficult to debug the problem if it is possible at least, also add the exception you getting

Comment: Hey Jakub, were you able to figure out the solution to this problem? I am at same issue at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

First, get numbers of `tr` elements in that table. Maybe similar to this (not tested):

```
${table_row_count}=    Get Element Count    xpath=//*[@id="tickets"]/tbody/tr
```

Then use the value in the last part of xpath:

```
Scroll Element Into View  xpath=//*[@id="tickets"]/tbody/tr[${table_row_count}]
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but It didn't work, with every use of `Scroll Element Into View` I stucked at the last visible element. After I tried to click on some element, which were not visible I received  `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`