# Get all rows from a table that has vertical bar in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a table which just shows 25 rows on inspection. It loads new set of rows on scrolling. But at a time there are only 25 rows that are visible. The ELEMENT also changes its ID from 1 to 25 to let's say 8 to 32 after little scroll. Point is it doesn't show entire content at any given time and only loads 25 IDs at any point. My requirement is to fetch all the rows(98) from the table. I have tried using `Scroll Element Into View`, but that has not helped me. Also using `Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)` has not helped as well.

I have seen so many questions on this one, but no appropriate solution to this.

[How to do scrolling inside infinite load table or list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59035165/2350068)

[Robot framework, Python - handle lazy load on page with dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44569549/2350068)

Please help if possible.

Comment: I was involved in a similar issue long time ago. I can't remember exactly how it was solved and I can't try it because I don't have an example page where I could test. But you could try sending down arrow keypresses to table element or scrolling table down with Javascript.

Comment: Hey @Pekka Can you please share link for such article?

Comment: That code ended in QWeb library: https://github.com/qentinelqi/qweb/blob/ba76e6d8d7b396e244312bf309c3258960d55049/QWeb/keywords/text.py#L1256

Comment: Thanks a ton @Pekka

Answer (score 0):

You have to write recursive keyword that would do following things:

1. Collects required data
2. Triggers loading of new rows (scrolls to the bottom, clicks button)
3. If there are new rows trigger this keyword once more
4. Combine results

Comment: Hey @JaPyR I am new to Robot Framework, Can you please help me in some resources to create such recursive keywords? Any links will be useful